# Kibana: Combine two fields to count

Tags: logstash, kibana

Situation:

I import logs via logstash into elasticsearch and then analyse the events with Kibana.
I have one event field with browser type and one event field with browser version.

Desired output in Kibana:

Make a pie chart where the two fields browser type and browser version are combined.
So if I have a value Firefox and a value 32.0 in the same event I want to see this in the pie chart presented as Firefox 32.0.

I probably should merge the fields via logstash, but I'm wondering if Kibana also offers the possibility to handle above situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kibana doesn't have that ability.  Your best bet is to combine them in logstash and make sure the field is `"index": "not_analyzed"`.